# C# Selenium - javascript generated table has no content

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a table which  content is generated via Javascript. 
When I am using selenium to get the body like so:

```
var elemTable = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div[8]/table/tbody"));
List<IWebElement> lstTrElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
```

I get empty results. The table results are visible only if I inspect the page if I open the page source I get the empty body. 
How can I get the content of the page that is dynamically generated?

Comment: did you print the size of this list ?

Comment: its empty - 0 elements

Comment: It could be in an iframe also. Check if it is in iframe.